# can i make my app (open with) windows menu with java (need examples)

Tags: java, windows, operating-system, open-with

i need some example to make my app as default text editor in java 
(i mean when I open the text file opens with my program)

How can I do that with Java ??

Comment: If you want to change a file association in Windows you can right click on it and go to properties, but surely that's not what you're asking.

Comment: Please read the question again
I mean make my app the default  (main) program
To open text files

Comment: [Official Microsoft Support - Change which programs Windows 7 uses by default](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/18539/windows-7-change-default-programs)

Comment: @ziondreamt Well, he want something else but actually asking that yeah.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer after many tests When i open the text file with my app from open with menu in windows

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
            FileReader file_reader = null;
        try {
            new Notepad().setVisible(true);
            file_reader = new FileReader(args[0]);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(file_reader);
            String temp = "";
            while (br.ready())
            {
                int c = br.read();
                temp = temp+ (char)c;
            }
            myarea.setText(temp);
            br.close();
            file_reader.close();
            textContent = myarea.getText();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Notepad.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Notepad.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {

        }
}
```

you must make your app exe